# Generate random walk on a graph

Tags: manipulate, graphs-and-networks, probability-or-statistics, animation

I have a graph with 100 nodes and 200 edges.  How can I generate a random walk in it and animate it?

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE! Your question needs more from your side. Here its considered helpful and polite to show your own efforts and share your data and code attempts in a well [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help), so we can quickly see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) accordingly. Also, please take the [tour], it will help you understand the site. If  you write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) it will inspire great answers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
Block[
 {
  graph = RandomGraph[{20, 100}]
  , start
  , path
  },
 start = RandomChoice[VertexList[graph]];
 path = NestList[RandomChoice[AdjacencyList[graph, #]] &, start, 5];
 ListAnimate[
  Table[
   Graph[graph
    , VertexStyle -> {v -> Red}
    , VertexSize -> Large
    ]
   , {v, path}
   ]]]
```

[image]

---

```
Block[
 {
  graph = GridGraph[{6, 6}]
  , start
  , path
  },
 start = RandomChoice[VertexList[graph]];
 path = NestList[RandomChoice[AdjacencyList[graph, #]] &, start, 30];
 ListAnimate[
  Table[
   Graph[
    graph
    , VertexStyle -> 
     Append[Map[Rule[#, Pink] &, Union[path[[1 ;; v]]]], 
      path[[v]] -> Red]
    , EdgeStyle -> 
     Evaluate[(UndirectedEdge[#1, #2] -> Directive[Red, Thick]) & @@@ 
       Partition[path[[1 ;; v]], 2, 1]]
    , VertexSize -> Large
    ]
   , {v, Length[path]}
   ]]]
```

[image]

Comment: I used your method in my modular graphs. It works wonderfully. Thank you. But what should i do if i want to start specifically at one node? @rhermans

Comment: You should try to understand the code, as it should be self evident if you have red the documentation for the functions I'm using. Change how `start` is defined, that is the starting vertex.

Comment: Okay. I got my results. Much thanks! @rhermans

Answer (score 10):

If you need good performance (e.g. compute hundreds of long random walks to get good statistics), consider using `IGRandomWalk` from [the IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM).

```
rg = RandomGraph[{100, 200}]

walk = IGRandomWalk[rg, 1, 100]

Animate[
 HighlightGraph[rg, vertex],
 {vertex, walk}
]
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`DiscreteMarkovProcess`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscreteMarkovProcess.html).

For example,

```
graph = GridGraph[{5, 5}]

mp = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1 (* starting vertex index, not name *), graph]

walk = RandomFunction[mp, {1, 10}]["Values"]
(* {1, 2, 1, 6, 11, 16, 11, 12, 7, 2} *)
```

Animate:

```
Animate[
 HighlightGraph[g, vertex],
 {vertex, walk}
]
```

Performance comparison with `IGRandomWalk` from IGraph/M:

```
RandomFunction[mp, {1, 10000}]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.034, Null} *)

IGRandomWalk[graph, 1, 10000]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.00038, Null} *)
```